# Background keep's repeating itself, even with no-repeat

Tags: css

```css
button {
  background:#fff;
  padding:0px;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  cursor:pointer;
  outline:none;
  width:140px;
  height:47px;
  color:#444;
}
.fave {
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url(https://cssanimation.rocks/assets/images/posts/steps/twitter_fave.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  padding:15px 50px;
}
.fave:hover {
  background-position: -3519px 0;
  transition: background 1s steps(55);
}
```

```html
<button><div class="fave">Save all</div></button>
```

So when you hover over the button, the star will repeat itself in the no-repeat zone (the zone where I don't want it to repeat). I've tried to make it no-repeat but that didn't work out so well.

I hope someone knows the problem here.

**EDIT**
It's hard to solve this problem, and I tried some things (guess that's not valid in W3C) which worked.

So my solution was putting the text under the star using position:

```css
button {
  background:#fff;
  padding:0px;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  cursor:pointer;
  outline:none;
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  color:#444;
  position:relative;
}
.fave {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url('https://cssanimation.rocks/assets/images/posts/steps/twitter_fave.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  padding:30px 30px;
}
.fave:hover {
  background-position: -3519px 0;
  transition: background 1.0s steps(55);
}
.txt {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:3.5px;
  left:2.5px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<button><div class="fave"><div class="txt">Opslaan</div></div></button>
```

Comment: I see only one star image and no more. I am using Chrome.

Comment: @Harry you can see repeated background after `hover`.

Comment: @Manwal: Even on hover, I see only one gold star.

Comment: @Harry can't believe my eyes i can see two starts after hover.

Comment: @Harry So when you hover over it, you can only see the 1 left star doing the animation?

Comment: There are two stars and I'm using Chrome, try increasing the width to maybe see it as it is partially cut of for me

Comment: @Manwal: I see two stars when I hover and add `-webkit-` prefix to the transition (because I am using a older version). So maybe the problem is to do with `transition` and not `background`.

Comment: technically `<button>` cannot contains `div`. because `<button>` are `inline` element.

Comment: @KheemaPandey I have to put it in the `<button>` so the star is inside the button.

Comment: I know the problem but i'm unsure of how to fix it.  If you search the image url on chrome it will display an image of about 20 non-animated stars, then if you run your code there is not actually 2 stars but there are 20 stars (if you increase the width so enough will fit on the button) and each star is animating but the image itself is not actually repeating

Comment: I'm thinking it's because you are transitioning `background` rather than the individual properties and so some are resetting.

Comment: Hi all, I've updated my post with a solution in it.

Comment: I have found solution for this situation. My be this is what `OP` want. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tweak css and HTML little bit: DEMO

```css
button {
  background:#fff;
  padding:0px;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  cursor:pointer;
  outline:none;
  width:140px;
  height:47px;
  color:#444;
}
.next{
  padding: 15px 3px;
      float: left;
}
.fave {
    float:left;
  width: 54px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url(https://cssanimation.rocks/assets/images/posts/steps/twitter_fave.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
button:hover .fave{
  background-position: -3519px 0;
  transition: background 1s steps(55);
}
```

```html
<button><div class="main">
    <div class="fave"></div>
    <div class="next">Save all</div>
    </div></button>
```